# How to get Sum of Associative array having specific key and value in php

Tags: php

I have to fetch sum of Amount field from given associative array according to TXNLineNo.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [TXNID] => 0
                [RefTXNID] => 1006
                [RefTXNObjectType] => 101
                [tmpTXNName] => CN-33
                [tmpTXNDate] => 2014-08-26
                [RefTXNLineNo] => 0
                [tmpOpenAmount] => 0
                [tmpOpenAmt] => -500.000
                [tmpTXNAmount] => 500
                [tmpNarration] => Being amount paid to supplier
                [Amount] => 500
                [TXNCurrencyID] => 213
                [ExchangeRate] => 1.00000
                [RevisionNumber] => 1
                [tmpRevisionNumber] => 1
                [RowState] => 435
                [tmpContactID] => 948
                [tmpAccountID] => 303
                [tmpBranchID] => 156
                [TXNLineNo] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [TXNID] => 0
                [RefTXNID] => 983
                [RefTXNObjectType] => 84
                [tmpTXNName] => RTY-01
                [tmpTXNDate] => 2014-08-26
                [RefTXNLineNo] => 1
                [tmpOpenAmount] => 0
                [tmpOpenAmt] => -1000.000
                [tmpTXNAmount] => 1000
                [tmpNarration] => 
                [Amount] => 1000
                [TXNCurrencyID] => 213
                [ExchangeRate] => 1.00000
                [RevisionNumber] => 1
                [tmpRevisionNumber] => 1
                [RowState] => 435
                [tmpContactID] => 948
                [tmpAccountID] => 303
                [tmpBranchID] => 156
                [TXNLineNo] => 1
            )
    [2] => Array
            (
                [TXNID] => 0
                [RefTXNID] => 1006
                [RefTXNObjectType] => 101
                [tmpTXNName] => CN-33
                [tmpTXNDate] => 2014-08-26
                [RefTXNLineNo] => 0
                [tmpOpenAmount] => 0
                [tmpOpenAmt] => -500.000
                [tmpTXNAmount] => 500
                [tmpNarration] => Being amount paid to supplier
                [Amount] => 500
                [TXNCurrencyID] => 213
                [ExchangeRate] => 1.00000
                [RevisionNumber] => 1
                [tmpRevisionNumber] => 1
                [RowState] => 435
                [tmpContactID] => 948
                [tmpAccountID] => 303
                [tmpBranchID] => 156
                [TXNLineNo] => 2
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [TXNID] => 0
                [RefTXNID] => 983
                [RefTXNObjectType] => 84
                [tmpTXNName] => RTY-01
                [tmpTXNDate] => 2014-08-26
                [RefTXNLineNo] => 1
                [tmpOpenAmount] => 0
                [tmpOpenAmt] => -1000.000
                [tmpTXNAmount] => 1000
                [tmpNarration] => 
                [Amount] => 1000
                [TXNCurrencyID] => 213
                [ExchangeRate] => 1.00000
                [RevisionNumber] => 1
                [tmpRevisionNumber] => 1
                [RowState] => 435
                [tmpContactID] => 948
                [tmpAccountID] => 303
                [tmpBranchID] => 156
                [TXNLineNo] => 2
            )
    )
```

I already use following script to get sum of `Amount` field

```
$ret = array_sum(array_map(function ($i) { return $i['Amount']; }, $data));
```

But this is not working for me. I have to fetch sum of amount `TxnLineNo Wise`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use something like this?

```
$amounts = array();
for($TxnLineNo = 0; $TxnLineNo < 3; $TxnLineNo++)   {
    $amounts[$TxnLineNo] = array_sum(array_map(function ($i) { global $TxnLineNo; return ($i['TXNLineNo']==$TxnLineNo)?$i['Amount']:0; }, $data));
}
var_dump($amounts);
```

Or, if you want a specific TxnLineNo, just (e.g. 2):

```
$ret = array_sum(array_map(function ($i) { return ($i['TXNLineNo']==2)?$i['Amount']:0; }, $data));
```

Comment: Can I add any variable instead of hard code value in second example.If is it possible then it's solve my problem..pls help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
/**
* @param $arr -> Your array
* @param $sum_ind -> which index value you want to sum(eg, Amount)
* @param $check_ind -> checking index (eg, TXNLineNo)
* @param $check_val -> Checking index value (eg,. 1, 2, ....)
* @return int -> Expected summation
*/
function getSumByIndex($arr, $sum_ind, $check_ind, $check_val){
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($arr as $val){
        if($val[$check_ind] == $check_val){
            $sum += $val[$sum_ind];
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you only want to sum a single thing, you could do a simple loop like this:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($whatever_your_array_is_called as $txtline_arr) {
    $sum += $txtline_arr['Amount'];
}
```